# How to change / assign a single icon in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, icons

I know there are icon themes. But what if we have a normal folder, just like a lot of others. Is it possible to change the icon of a specific folder alone, say `family` into an icon of my choice ?

I was looking for something like `right-click > properties > change icon` so that all other folders will use globally declared folder icons while the one of our choice will have a custom icon. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of right-clicking the folder, and select "Properties" in the right-click menu. On the "Basic" tab, click the icon. A file selection dialog appears that allows you to set a custom icon.